# Paste another image into an image with with Pillow (Python) respecting transparency

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have two 320x320 pixels png images and I need to paste one above the other with Python (the parts that are not colored are transparent):

[image]
[image]

When I do it manually with GIMP (copy+paste), it gives me the desired output:

[image]

However, when pasting one above the other with Pillow I get an image of the red circle as if there was no transparency:

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open("square.png")
im2 = Image.open("circle.png")

im1.paste(im2)
im1
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open("square.png")
im2 = Image.open("circle.png")
```

im2 paste on im1

```
Image.Image.paste(im1,im2,mask=im2)

im1.show()
```

here you can specify image as mask as im2

or you can use directly as

```
im1.paste(im2,mask=im2)
```